# I want to dynamically show a background image in a div with text, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my ASP.NET MVC 3/jQuery/HTML5 based web app (I figure MVC is irrelevant in this context), I have a `div` element in the view, which is updated with text from an operation running on the server. When the server operation finishes, I'd like to add a background image to the `div` symbolizing success or failure.

The containing `div` is of variable width, so I figure the image needs to scale (while conserving proportions). In order to allow the image to scale, I guess it needs to be SVG format as well?

How do you suggest I go about updating the `div` element with a background image, in JavaScript/jQuery, based on my requirements? Let me know if I need to specify further.

**EDIT**

I'd also appreciate recommendations of free of charge icons for symbolizing success/failure states :)

Comment: Does the server return a JSON status whether it is successful or fail?

Comment: @momo That doesn't really matter. I have one JS callback that gets called on success and vice versa. I only need to worry about updating of the view.

Comment: I am asking because if the server doesn't return JSON with success/fail boolean, you could just return an HTML containing the img that you append to the div. Alternatively, you could just put img tag with default src to be blank image that you update depending on the success/failure in the callback. Tim's answer  provides the jQuery template that you could modify

Comment: @momo Does it matter though if the HTML is rendered server-side or added through jQuery? I need to figure out how to write the HTML/CSS anyway :) Besides, `<img>` wouldn't render a background image would it? I figure I need to use the CSS `background-image` property, or some such.

Comment: It's easier if it is done through server side. jQuery has load() function for that and you don't have to code the javascript. You are right about the image, I misunderstood that you want the text on top of the image :) It seems you already know about background-image so you are almost there if you could figure out the image scaling part. I've never tried background with SVG (not even sure it will work). Have to experiment a bit before giving formal answer. Hopefully someone else could help you with that before.

Comment: I did find a [recipe for SVG as background via CSS](http://helephant.com/2009/08/12/svg-images-as-css-backgrounds/), but I could only make it work if I swapped SVG for PNG :/

Comment: I got the answer to my problem through [a differently formulated question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7308883/265261).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to include a background SVG through the CSS property `background-image`. Furthermore, `background-size: contain` allowed the background image to scale with the div (excellent!). Example CSS:

```
div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Konqi_svg.svg);
}
```

For a working example, see my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXTWt/).

I understand this solution requires newer browsers, such as IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, SVG is not mandatory and not supported by all browsers. Any image format will be fit. Just keep the ratio if you resize it.

If I were, I would use ajax methods with jQuery and take necessary actions with the ajax request's result.

For example;

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'aa.html',
                    beforeSend: function() { $('#loader').fadeIn("slow"); },
                    complete: function() { $('#loader').fadeOut("slow"); },
                    success: function(data){
                            $("#page").html(data);
                            $("#page").fadeIn("slow");
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            $("#page").html(jqXHR + ' ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                            $("#page").fadeIn("slow");
                    }
            });
    });
```

You can modify this example as you wish and may follow the link for complete ajax reference of jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ajax methods aren't relevant here, as I get called back by SignalR (which is a Comet-like framework).

Comment: I don't think your example fits my case, as you reset `#page`'s HTML content completely? In my case, I seek to change the background image of a `div`. Also, won't there be a problem with scaling non-vector images? I figure the background should scale as the view is resized, although I might be asking too much here :)

Comment: If you keep the ratio, image will looks fine.

You can update the DIV's background with jQuery again.

$("#DIV_ID").css("background-image",'url(...)');

Comment: In addition to updating of the DOM, I really need to know how I should add the background picture in HTML/CSS and if I can use SVG etc. I've tried to add an SVG with CSS property `background-image`, but it doesn't show in Chrome. PNG on the other hand works.

Comment: As I said, SVG is not fully supported by browsers. Its better to choose another format.