# Can I display an SVG image as a div background with a JavaScript SVG library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In an HTML page, I want to use an SVG image as a background in a `div` element, with a `pre` element with text on top of of it (the background). The background image should scale with the containing `div`, while maintaining aspect ratio.

Can I accomplish this task with one of the SVG JavaScript libraries, such as [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.htmlhttp://keith-wood.name/svg.html) / [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) / [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/)?

The kind of structure I'd like to add a background image to:

```
<div>
  <pre>Some text...</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: What browsers do you need to support, most only added support for using SVG as a background image in the last 12 months or so.

Comment: @robertc At the moment I'm concentrating on IE9, current Chrome and current Firefox. I haven't been able to make neither IE9 nor Chrome show SVG as background image yet though :( Replace .svg with .png and it works.

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you want to generate the SVG using JavaScript and then use it as a background. Is that so, or did you only want to reference an existing SVG file hosted as a standalone file and use that as a background?

Comment: @Phrogz I want to load an existing SVG image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an SVG image as a CSS background, providing you only want to support recent browsers, [use `background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) to scale the image and maintain the aspect ratio.  Here the image is applied directly to the `pre`, just to [demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/c9LgV/):

```
pre {
    outline: 2px dashed black;
    padding: 1em;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Konqi_svg.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If you want to support IE8 and FF3.6 then you'll have to resort to absolutely positioned elements as andrewmu suggests.

Comment: I've found now that the reason that SVG doesn't work for me as `background-image` is that the Visual Studio development server serves the SVG with MIME type 'application/octet-stream'. If I point to the Konqi SVG on wikimedia on the other hand, the SVG gets rendered in the browser :( Is this a known problem? Any idea how to force correct serving of SVGs?

Comment: @aknuds1 What version of Visual Studio/.Net/IIS?  In 2010/4/7.5 add a [`mimeMap` in web.config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx).  In 2008/3.5/6 you need to configure it under HTTP Headers in IIS Management.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate/.NET 4.0. I'm not using IIS on this dev box. Does the VS dev server support the mimeMap setting or similar?

Comment: @aknuds1 I'm not sure, I've only used it with IIS, try it and see.

Comment: After looking around a bit, it seems that the standard VS dev server (Cassini) doesn't support such configuration. However, the replacement [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) does. I'm going to try that, thanks!

Comment: Now that I've sorted the server problem (yay CassiniDev!), let's get back to the actual question... As [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/c9LgV/) demonstrates, the background SVG doesn't scale with the containing element, as I'd like. Can it be accomplished?

Comment: What browser are you looking at it in?  It scales for me in Firefox 6, check out the `background-size` link in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3198/discussion-between-aknuds1-and-robertc)

Comment: This answer works for me, except that I use `background-size: contain`  instead of `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 2):

You could always cheat and use `position: absolute` to put two `div`s in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>SVG images are part of the DOM they cannot be a div background, instead they are an element just like a div.</strike>

You could place an SVG image behind a transparent div to get the illusion of a background.  This just involves positing your SVG and content in the proper place.

to get scaling you should use some math to maintain aspect ratio, should be pretty easy, the word ratio is involved. That would be a clue on how to do that.

**EDIT**

It looks like I was wrong
http://www.broken-links.com/2010/06/08/using-svg-in-background-image/ it can be a background.

Comment: Could you outline your suggested solution? Could you make the SVG scale with the containing div?

Comment: I added that.  How you implement it can change from what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you recommend a particular library?

Comment: I like raphael but again it really depends on what you need

Comment: I think I'd need some advice on how to place the SVG and the transparent `div` element on top of each other, within the containing `div`.

Comment: Try a couple things then ask a new question.  I cannot write your code for you.  I will tell you it will involve drawing the graphic with your svg library, creating a div, and then positioning them with css or I am willing to help you in chat if you need any more explaining

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3176/discussion-between-austinbv-and-aknuds1)

Comment: Of course an SVG can be a background, it's an image format just as much as PNG or JPG is.